# Search with lazy quantifier

Tags: vim, macvim

I have the following text:

```
Nmap  scan report for abc.com (127.0.20.231)
...
Nmap  scan report for 123456.com (127.0.20.13)
...
Nmap  scan report for qwerty.com (127.0.20.28)
...
```

and want to get the following out of it:

```
abc.com
123456.com
qwerty.com
```

I can do it outside of vim, it should be like `(?<=report for )(.*?)(?= )`, but I don't understand how I can do it in vim.

As far as I understand it should be something similar to my solution in very magic mode. Can anyone show different examples for vim?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct translation to Vim's dialect, see `:help perl-patterns`:

```
\(report for \)\@<=\(.\)\{-}\( \)\@=/
```

But that thing is only a pattern which does nothing on its own. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: thx, it works. isn't there an easier way?
I just want to copy the text that will be found (know how to do it).

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry; I mean, is there no other way to select the text between two specific words in vim? In my case it is everything between "report for " and " (".
Your example works, but it looks very tricky.

Comment: "Select" for what? For yanking? For storing in a variable? For syntax highlighting? For navigation? In visual mode? You have to explain your goal, here. Also, my "example" is just a verbatim translation of yours so it's not trickier.

Comment: Select for yanking. But I copy the selected text with the CopyMatches function (https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Copy_search_matches). So, all I have to do is mark the text to copy it.
I can select "report for abc.com " with `/\vreport for\ .*\ ` to copy it later, but what I really need to select is only "abc.com".

Comment: Which is matched by provided pattern. Not sure what you want more.

Comment: @romainl - I assume OP wants to either delete all that does not match or have all matches yanked into a register. Something like `let @q=''|g/report for \zs.*\ze (/norm gn"Qy` but with crlf after each match. Something I always use powershell for to be honest (or Powergrep) because I can't for the life of me remember how to do it with vim.

Comment: A naive approach would be something like `:v//d_` followed by `%norm 0dnf "_d$`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, OP already has a plugin that is supposed to yank the last matched text so now that they have a working pattern it seems that they are good to go.

Comment: No argument there :)

Comment: Yeah, I just tried OP's plugin and, combined with the given pattern, it does exactly what OP is asking. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern like `/report for \zs.*\ze`  to only match the `abc.com`.

See `\zs` and `\ze` about setting the start and end of a match. They are more intuitive than `\@<=` and `\@=`.